# Disable Visual Studio 2022 Spelling Check (and solve warnings)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

For a few days we see on different projects and on different machines a new warning entry "Spelling Error".

[image]

We already have disabled different extensions but we think it's a Visual Studio 2022 Feature (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/676713/visual-studio-2022-spell-checker-settings-and-cont)

We suspect that it is a feature of VS Preview, because we do not get the warnings under VS 17.4.4. None of the systems have been updated recently, with no updates since before Christmas anyway.

Unfortunately, we cannot find a setting anywhere to deactivate the spell check. We could only exclude that the warnings come from another source (.NET CLI...).

Where exactly could the warnings come from and how can we deactivate the Spellcheck, which according to the warnings does not work anyway?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-Preview-displays-spelling-error-m/10255396?q=spelling&sort=votes

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant - the feedback search showed me results from 2017 but not that thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It has been fixed with Version 17.5.0 Preview 3.0.
Still a weird remote feature activation...

Comment: I'm on 17.6.2 and I can't turn it off (It's crap I have an extension that does a better job, without adding comments into the code base.